# Define a DFA that accepts all even length binary strings that don't contain the substring "111"?

Tags: finite-automata, discrete-mathematics

I think I have worked out a DFA that doesn't accept the substring "111," but I don't know how to account for accepting even length strings. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated! [image]

Comment: I think you would have to keep track of parity. One set of states for an odd number of bits seen, another for an even number.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that DFA has a "finite" memory, each state knows something about what you've read so far.
$A$ remembers that so far, you've read $w0$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ or $\epsilon$.
$B$ remembers that so far, you've read $w01$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ or $1$.
and so on...

Now you can duplicate the states to have the following properties:
$A_{even}$ means that so far you've read $w0$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ or $\epsilon$, and you've read even number of letters.
$A_{odd}$ means that so far you've read $w0$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$, and you've read odd number of letters ($\epsilon$ has even number of letters, so it's not included here).
$B_{even}$ remembers that so far, you've read $w01$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$, and you've read even number of letters.
$B_{odd}$ remembers that so far, you've read $w01$ for some $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ or $1$, and you've read odd number of letters.

And so on.
You need to re-define your transition function and and accept states to match with the definition of these new states

Edit: I misread the question as accepting '111' as a substring, so the definition of A,B that i showed are a bit off, but the answer to your question is similar in concept.

Comment: This is much, much better than [your other answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/101303/9550). Thanks!